# WooCommerce - Transpose Cart loop in Order loop for pdf invoices

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, invoices

I'm using woocommerce and "Print Invoices & Packing lists"
 available at "https://woocommerce.com/products/print-invoices-packing-lists/" .
For Display the Total Saving in the woocommerce cart & checkout pages I'm used this code and works perfectly :

```
 function bbloomer_wc_discount_total() {

    global $woocommerce;

    $cart_subtotal = $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents;

    $discount_total = 0;

  foreach ($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product_data) {

        if ($product_data['variation_id'] > 0) {
            $product = wc_get_product( $product_data['variation_id'] );
        } else {
            $product = wc_get_product( $product_data['product_id'] );
        }

        if ( !empty($product->sale_price) ) {
        $discount = ($product->regular_price - $product->sale_price) * $product_data['quantity'];
        $discount_total += $discount;
        }

    }

    if ( $discount_total > 0 ) {
    echo '<tr class="cart-discount">
    <th>'. __( 'Total Saving :', 'woocommerce' ) .'</th>
    <td data-title=" '. __( 'Total Saving :', 'woocommerce' ) .' ">'
    . wc_price($discount_total+$woocommerce->cart->discount_cart) .'</td>
    </tr>';
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_order_total', 'bbloomer_wc_discount_total');
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total', 'bbloomer_wc_discount_total');
```

This function based in the woocommerce cart contents .
 How I can Display The Total Saving in the Html Invoice generated By Print Invoices & Packing lists Plugin ( based On the Order Instead of the cart contents ) in the plugin Hooks like :

> add_action( 'wc_pip_after_header', 'bbloomer_wc_discount_total');
>   add_action( 'wc_pip_document_header', 'bbloomer_wc_discount_total');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**— Update 2 —** *(Added compatibility for WooCommerce version 3+)*

> Now as I know you are using **WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips** plugin.

This code can only be used directly in **`invoice.php`** PIP template at the beginning, replacing **`<?php global $wpo_wcpdf ?>`** by this:

```
<?php 

    global $wpo_wcpdf, $woocommerce;

    // Get the order object
    $_order = $wpo_wcpdf->export->order;

    foreach ( $_order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // Added WC 3+ compatibility
        $quantity = method_exists( $item, 'get_quantity' ) ? $item->get_quantity() : $item['quantity'];
        $variation_id = method_exists( $item, 'get_variation_id' ) ? $item->get_variation_id() : $item['variation_id'];
        $_product = version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ? wc_get_product( $item['product_id'] ) : $item->get_product();

        // Get the product object when it's a product variation ( Before version WC 3+)
        if ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ) 
            if ($item['variation_id'] > 0) $_product = wc_get_product( $item['variation_id'] );

        // Get prices
        $sale_price = $_product->get_sale_price();
        $regular_price = $_product->get_regular_price();

        // Only when sale price exits
        if ( ! empty( $sale_price ) && $sale_price > 0 ) {
            $discount = ($regular_price - $sale_price) * $item->get_quantity();
            $discount_total += $discount;
        }

    }
    if ( $discount_total > 0 ) {
        $display_discount = '<tr class="cart-discount">
            <th>'. __( 'Total you saved :', 'woocommerce' ) .'</th>
            <td data-title=" '. __( 'Total you saved :', 'woocommerce' ) .' ">' . wc_price( $discount_total + $_order->get_total_discount() ) .'</td>
        </tr>';
    }

?>
```

Then you can use it where you want in the template to output it, this way (inside html):

```
<?php echo $display_discount; ?>
```

Or (inside php code):

```
echo $display_discount;
```

This code is tested and works.

Comment: Thanks to your response .

I have been added this code to my functions.php in the my template , and using the Woocommerce pip plugin , then in the html invoice page displays : Fatal error: Call to a member function get_items() on boolean

Comment: Hi Thanks alot for your response , I'm using "WooCommerce Print Invoices & Packing Lists"  , and this is my plugin you can download : https://www.dropbox.com/s/7mmsuh7o0tjaa45/woocommerce-pip.zip?dl=0 and this is the Hooks refrence : https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-print-invoices-packing-lists-developer-reference/ . what code i can add to my functions.php to displays Total Saving in the Html Invoices ? thank you very much !

Comment: Thanks a lot , can i add your code to my functions.php . How I can using of your code ?  Thank you

Comment: Thanks , But i don't using the "WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips" plugin . I am using "Print Invoices & Packing lists" available at "https://woocommerce.com/products/print-invoices-packing-lists/" and my plugin don't have this function : $wpo_wcpdf . How i can use your code with "Print Invoices & Packing lists" Plugin ?